# R function returns empty dataframe but same code out of the function works

Tags: r, function

I apologize if this has already been solved elsewhere. I found a similar question but there was no relevant answer.

**What I am trying to do:** Creating a function that selects relevant observations in three different datasets by country code, makes basic operations on these observations, then join them by common variable "Date"

More precisely, I am using OWID's covid datasets and my function is attempting to create a dataframe that contains the relevant information for a given country originally spread across two files.

The code is below:

owid_may5 is the Our World in Data testing dataset

owid_totalcases_may5 is the Our World in Data confirmed cases dataset

owid_daily_may5 is the Our World in Data confirmed deaths dataset

"country" in the function argument is an ISO countrycode

```
    TreatCountry<- function(country) {
    ##This part of the function selects the data in relevant datasets
        filtered_country_tests <- owid_may5 %>% filter(Code=='country') 
        filtered_country_cases <- owid_totalcases_may5 %>% filter(Code=='country')
        filtered_country_deaths<- owid_daily_may5 %>% filter(Code=='country')
    ##This part of the function adds "Newtest" and "Newcases" columns calculated from the cumulative totals in the previous datasets
        filtered_country_tests$Newtests <- diff( c(0, filtered_country_tests$Total.tests))
        filtered_country_cases$Newcases <- diff( c(0, filtered_country_cases$cases ) )
##This part of the function joins the three datasets and then turns the result into POSIXt.
        joined<- inner_join(filtered_country_tests,filtered_country_cases,by='Date')
        joined<- inner_join(joined,filtered_country_deaths,by='Date')
        joined$Date <- anytime(c(joined$Date))
        return(joined)
      }
```

As a result I get a dataframe with 12 variables (as expected) but...0 observations.

Now for the weird part:
**When I type the exact same code but replace "country" by any countrycode, the code works as expected and I end up with a dataframe with all relevant variables and observations.**

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Try and unquote country inside your function from Code == 'country' to Code== country

Comment: Thanks e.matt ! I just tried but no luck. I get
 Error: object 'IND' not found

Comment: For reference here is the (str) of one of the dataframes I use (owid_may5)
The others are structured similarly

'data.frame': 4093 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Entity     : Factor w/ 88 levels "Argentina","Australia",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Code       : Factor w/ 83 levels "","ARG","AUS",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Date       : Factor w/ 125 levels "Apr 1, 2020",..: 29 30 2 3 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Total.tests: int  13330 14850 16379 18027 19758 22805 24374 26457 28650 30942 ...

Comment: And...It works now, if I follow your advice but type the function as
TreatCountry('country') 
So putting the quotes inside the argument call.
I don't think I usually have to do that.
Any idea why it's behaving like this?
Thank you very much anyway!

Comment: The function won't actually be calling your input, as country is already used within function. IF you did want it to be flexible and filter on another Code, it would be best to unquote country in your funtion and call. Your function should then accept a string input that you want to filter Code on.